# Creating a .pkg installer that makes use of another product .pkg

Tags: node.js, macos, pkgbuild

I'm building a OS X `.pkg` installer for a product that requires NodeJS.

I'm experimenting with the possibility of embedding the [official NodeJS pkg installer](http://nodejs.org/download/) as a component package of my installer.

I downloaded the official pkg to `packages/node.pkg` and modified my `distribution.xml` to look like this:

```
...
        <pkg-ref id="org.nodejs.pkg">node.pkg</pkg-ref>

        <choices-outline>
                <line choice="org.nodejs.pkg" />
        </choices-outline>

        <choice
                id="org.nodejs.pkg"
                visible="false"
                title="nodejs"
                description="NodeJS"
                start_selected="true">
            <pkg-ref id="org.nodejs.pkg" />
        </choice>
...
```

However, when building with `productbuild`:

```
productbuild --distribution distribution.xml \
    --resources resources \
    --package-path packages \
    --version 0.2.3 \
    setup.pkg
```

I get the following warning:

```
productbuild: warning: package packages/node.pkg could not be loaded
```

I discarded the possibility that `packages/node.pkg` could not exist for some reason (maybe I downloaded the pkg into another location):

```
$ file packages/node.pkg
packages/node.pkg: xar archive - version 1
```

What am I missing?

Is it because I'm trying to use a product package as a component package of my own product package?

Another possibility is to run `installer` within my package scripts to get it installed, however I'm wondering if there is a better way to express dependencies between `pkg`'s.

Answer (score 0):

It is not finding the node.js package. You should modify following line with the correct path:

```
<pkg-ref id="org.nodejs.pkg">node.pkg</pkg-ref>
```

If you have bundled node.pkg INSIDE your package as a component package, you should use the following: (Note the use of # before the package name)

```
<pkg-ref id="org.nodejs.pkg">#node.pkg</pkg-ref>
```

If you have kept the node.pkg outside your package (Let's say it is present at the same directory alonside your pkg), then you can use relative paths:

```
<pkg-ref id="org.nodejs.pkg">node.pkg</pkg-ref>
```